# How to pass parameters into a function in Context Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-context

I need to call a parameterized function which is in Context from another component. Below is the code snippet.

Context

```
Sortdata=(id)=> {
        console.log("passed from homepage",id)
         if(this.state.data>parseInt(id)){
        recorddata.sort((a,b)=>{
            let da = new Date(a.inspectioN_DT),
            db = new Date(b.inspectioN_DT);
        return da - db;}
    });
        console.log(recorddata);
        this.setState({
            listvalues: recorddata
        })
    }

 render() { 
        return ( 
            <DataContext.Provider value={{...this.state, sortData: this.Sortdata }}>
                {this.props.children}
            </DataContext.Provider>
           
         );
    }
```

I need to call the above function **Sortdata()** from my home component.Please suggest me a way to do call this function or a alternative using react context itself. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html, much quicker to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

First create your context

```
const DataContext= React.createContext('');
```

Pass in the value which you did already (which is the object with the function)

```
 <DataContext.Provider value={{...this.state, sortData: this.Sortdata }}>
```

Accessing the context (must be inside provider)

```
const value = useContext(DataContext);
```

Example of calling function:

```
value.sortData(3);
```

See more at: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext and https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: Hi @anthony_718 , I have tried the method but it is showing a error as sortData is not a function.  I want to use call this function from another class component. Currently I am accessing the state in the Context like below

`static contextType = DataContext;

const {Userlist, Roles, Devices} = this.context;`